# Trying to alter a text file in java

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors, split

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Filter{ 

    Message myMessage;
    Scanner input;
    Scanner input2; 
    String sender;  
    String subject;
    String emailMIN;
    String line;
    String line2;
    ArrayList<String> blacklist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> subjectWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
    //String[] lines;
    File SpamMessage;
    File inFile;
    File inFile2;
    File  tempFile;
    String[] lines;



    public Filter(Message m,String blacklistFile, String keywordFile, String Spam)throws IOException{
            inFile = new File(blacklistFile);
            inFile2 = new File(keywordFile);  
            input = new Scanner (inFile);
            input2 = new Scanner (inFile2);
                                                                                                  myMessage =m;
            SpamMessage=new File(Spam);
    }


    public void filter() throws IOException{
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(SpamMessage);
            while(input.hasNextLine()){
                    line = input.nextLine();
                    //System.out.println(line);
                    if(line!=null)
                           blacklist.add(line);
            }       
            while(input2.hasNextLine()){
                    line2 = input2.nextLine();
                    //System.out.println(line2);
                    if(line!=null)
                            keywords.add(line2);
            }

            emails=myMessage.getEmails();
    //      System.out.println(emails.size() + emails.get(1));
            for(int i = 0; i < emails.size(); i++){
    //              boolean isSpam = false;
                    lines = emails.get(i).split("\n");
    //              System.out.println(lines[5] + lines[7]);
                    sender = lines[2].substring(lines[2].indexOf('<'), lines[2].indexOf('>'));
    //`             System.out.println(sender);
                    emailMIN = lines[6].substring(lines[6].indexOf('<'), lines[6].indexOf('>'));
    //              System.out.println(emailMIN);
                    for(int j =0; j<lines.length; j++)
                    {
                            if(j==2)
                            {
                                    for(String blacklist2: blacklist)
                                    {
                            //              System.out.println(blacklist2);
                                            if(lines[j].contains(blacklist2))
                                            {
                                           output.println(emailMIN);
                                            }
                            //              output.close();
                                    }
                            }
                            if(j==5 || j>=7)
                            {
                            //      System.out.println(keywords.size());
                                    for(String keywords2: keywords)
                                    {
                            //              System.out.println(keywords2);
                                            if(lines[j].contains(keywords2))
                                            {
                                                    output.println(emailMIN);
                                            }
                                    //      output.close();
                                    }
                            }
                    //addKeywords();
            }

    }
    output.close();
    addKeywords();
    }

    public void addKeywords() throws IOException
    {
            tempFile = new File("tempFile.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

            for(int i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
            {
                    if(i==5){
                            String[] words = lines[i].split(" ");
                            for(String word: words){
                                    if(word.length()>=6){
                                            subjectWords.add(word +"\n");
                                            //System.out.println(subjectWords);
                                    }
                            }               
                            keywords.addAll(subjectWords);
                            pw.println(keywords);

                    }
            }               
            pw.close();
            if (!inFile2.delete()) {
                    //System.out.println("Could not delete file");
                    return;
            }               

    // Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
            if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile2)){
                    //System.out.println("Could not rename file");
            }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to update the list of words in the keywords txt file right now it does update it but it puts it in the format [generic, pharmacy, little, inside]

Which is wrong because then if I run my code again it is searching if the file contains [generic, pharmacy, little, inside] and I need it to search for every word not the plus a comma or brace. So basically I want it to copy the words in a list format like this

```
generic
pharmacy
little
inside
```

That way it searches for each individual word. I figured out how to do this part. Now, how do I add the senders to a different text file? Also is there a way to modify this so it doesn't add the same keywords twice? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are writing an array to the file which causes the `toString` method of it to be called. Write every single item instead.

Instead of `pw.println(keywords);`

Do:

```
for (String keyword : keywords)
 { 
   pw.println(keyword.trim());
 }
```

Or, if every word contains \n already, this should work

```
for (String keyword : keywords)
 { 
   pw.print(keyword);
 }
```

Comment: How do I do that? I'm sorry I don't have a lot of time and if you could show me how to do it I would really appreciate it

Comment: Ok that works but it puts spaces in between each list item so now it searches for spaces too when I run it again

Comment: in between every word there is an empty line so it skips a line in between every word on the text file list

Comment: Never mind I fixed it I realized that I had something to skip lines in my code

Comment: @user2977165 You should consider accepting some answers. Not only on this question but on all your questions. People took time to help you, the least you can do is accept the answer

Comment: Do I have to press the check mark or something? I don't really know how this site works

Comment: @user2977165 There is a check mark next to each answer. Click on it

Comment: does anyone know how I can do the same sort of thing but add the sender to a different text file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
pw.println(keywords);
```

you should instead loop through the array and add each line individually.

```
for(int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    pw.println(keywords[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That was because you are printing an `ArrayList` object. In your code, `keywords` is instance of the List and which would you give you an output of [aa,bb] . More over you would get duplicate words since these list instance are class variables, and printed inside a loop

```
 keywords.addAll(subjectWords);
 pw.println(keywords);
```

Either you can loop around `keywords` outside the for loop or print the `word`  before adding to list.